# I want to close the modal when react esc is pressed

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

We are using react and styled-components.
When the button is pressed, the modal(drawer) is displayed from the right.
I want the modal to be closed when the esc button is pressed.
How do I detect that the esc button has been pressed?
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dawn-s5f3x?file=/src/components/Drawer.tsx:0-896)

```
import Drawer from "./components/Drawer";
import { FunctionComponent, useState } from "react";

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const onClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>button</button>
      <Drawer isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}></Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

type Props = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  padding?: number;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClose: () => void;
  handleKeyDown: () => void;
};

export default (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Overlay isOpen={props.isOpen} onClick={props.onClose} />
      <DrawerModal {...props}>{props.children}</DrawerModal>
    </>
  );
};

const DrawerModal = styled.div<Props>`
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: ${({ isOpen }: Props) => (isOpen ? 400 : 0)}px;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.24, 1);
`;

const Overlay = styled.div<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: ${(props: { isOpen: boolean }) => (props.isOpen ? 0 : -1)};
`;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an effect like this to handle keyboard events like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleEscapeKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === 'Escape') {
      setIsOpen(false)
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleEscapeKey)
  return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscapeKey)
}, [])
```

The effect declares a function that handle a `keydown` event and checks if the escape key was pressed. Then it binds that event handler to the document. When the component is removed, it cleans up by removing the event handler from the document.

Comment: hey alex, may I know why is it necessary to stop propagation in this case ?

Comment: @Codenewbie Huh, you're right! I don't think it is necessary.